# I cannot redirect to another page using ajax when use the php base_url

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, redirect, window.location, base-url

I am trying to redirect to another page when condition is true using ajax. But I cannot do it when I use the php base_url.  But If I give the direct path (http://localhost/CRH/......), it works. I cannot find what the issue is use of base url. Please help...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeing PHP code client-side then your PHP isn't executing at all.

This is probably because you've put this PHP code in a `.js` file.  That's for JavaScript, not for PHP.

It's understandable that you're going to want to keep your JavaScript separate from your HTML.  However, PHP-generated values are probably still going to have to be in the HTML since they need to come from PHP files.

(You *could* configure your web server to process `.js` files for PHP code, or put your JavaScript code in a PHP file and set the headers to return JavaScript.  But those seem like a bit of overkill for this.)

What you could do is emit a simple JavaScript value to your HTML in your `.php` file, something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var baseUrl = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>';
</script>
```

Then in your JavaScript file you'd be able to reference that value:

```
window.location = baseUrl + 'index.php?etc.';
```